# Retrieving JSON elements that don't share a key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
"names": {
"jack": {
  "probability": 0
},
"bob": {
  "probability": 0.5
},
"ana": {
  "probability": 0.2
}
"bill": {
}
```

And I want to query it to get a table of names and probabilities, and in case there is no value of probability, get 0.
So the output should look like this:

```
name      probability
jack      0
bob       0.5
ana       0.2
bill      0
```

Couldn't find a way to query the json in a proper way to get these results. I am using Postgresql.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed! Either an array with []. or objects within objects.. then a missing }...

Comment: just check the field for being null

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `jsonb_each()` function:

```sql
select n.name, coalesce(val ->> 'probability', '0')::numeric
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each( t.col -> 'names') as n(name, val)
```

If you column isn't `jsonb` (which it should), but `json`, you have to use `json_each()` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=38bbceb2b633d0281928de412410aa8a)